# How to plot SMA value for the current candle in a Startegy?

Tags: pine-script

When I plot SMA in a Study, it plots the SMA value for the current candle.

When I plot SMA in a Strategy, it doesn't.

Is there a way to plot the SMA for the current candle in a Strategy?

**Study**

```
//@version=4
study(title="Study:Moving Average",overlay=true)
SMA = sma(close,30)
plot(SMA)
```

**Strategy**

```
//@version=4
strategy(title="Strategy:Moving Average",overlay=true)
SMA = sma(close,30)
plot(SMA)
```

[Study and Strategy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/USh4L.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because by default, strategies only run on the realtime bar's close. You can have strategies run like studies on every realtime price/volume update by using [`calc_on_every_tick = true`](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v4/#fun_strategy) in your `strategy()` call.

If you do, keep in mind that you will not be running the same strategy you backtested on historical bars, where only OHLC values are available.